# loop "functions" and "for loops" through list of dataframes

Tags: r

Hy. 
I'm working with shapefiles in R. I wrote a script which processes one of my shapefiles. Therefore I wrote mutliple functions and for loops. After processing the shapefile it will be written to another folder. Now i need to apply this to all my shapefiles. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm new to R.

What I've got sofar:
Script for one shapefile, which looks like this:
Upload the file and set time format:

```
setwd("")
shape=ReadOGR(dsn=", layer= "Trip_2")
shape$Zeit= as.POSIXct(strptime(shape$Zeit_txt, format= "%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT"), tz="GMT")
```

First extractions: make Wegtyp NA if Count is not 1

```
shape$wegtyp[shape$Count != 1] = NA
shape$name_wegty[shape$Count != 1] = NA
shape$OBJECTVAL[shape$Count != 1] = NA
shape$name_weg_1[shape$Count != 1] = NA
```

First Function:

```
calculateDistancesWGS = function(long, lat){
  distWGS = long
  distWGS = NA
  for (i in 1:(length(lat)-1)){
    distWGS[i+1] = distCosine( c(long[i+1], lat[i+1]), c(long[i], lat[i]))
  }
  return(distWGS)
}

shape$distanceWGS = calculateDistancesWGS(shape$longitude, shape$latitude)
```

several more function follow

extract file as shapefile:

```
 writeOGR(shape, dsn= "", layer= "Trip_03", driver= "ESRI Shapefile" )
```

Now I need to do this with all my shapefiles and save them with different names.
I'm able to import several shapefiles to R creating a list of dataframes like this:

```
 setwd("")
list_shp <-        list.files(path="", pattern="*.shp", full.names = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = FALSE)
shapes <- lapply(list_shp, function(x) {readOGR(dsn=x,     layer=ogrListLayers(x))})
```

But when it gets to applying the timeformat and the functions i could not figure out what to do.

Here's  a short example of my data:

```
d1= data.frame(longitude=(10.42206), latitude= (46.60109), Wegtyp= (1),     Zeit_txt= 14.50)
d2= data.frame (longitude= (10.42207), latitude= (46.60108), Wegtyp= 2, Zeit_txt= (14.55))
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can just `lapply` a function that does the command you wanted, like the following:

```
addTime <- function(shape) { 
  shape$Zeit= as.POSIXct(strptime(shape$Zeit_txt, format= "%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT"), tz="GMT")
  return(shape)
}
shapes <- lapply(shapes, addTime)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly and I now unterstand what it does. Could you also give me an example how to do this for the first function? Do I have to make a function around a function here? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Since it's a list of data.frames, you'll want to wrap the part that adds the column to the data.frame in a function, and lapply as above. For example: `addDistance <- function(shape) shape$distanceWGS = calculateDistancesWGS(shape$longitude, shape$latitude); return(shape)`

Comment: Works. Exactly the solution i was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mhhm, another question. I figured out how to apply your suggestions to all my functions. 
However I'm now stuck at writing each dataframe as a new shapefile. 
I'd like the name to be shape_1, shape_2 and so on. I use writeOGR to save as shapefile. 
Here's my code for one shapefile:   
    `writeOGR(shapes, dsn= "", layer= "shape_1", driver= "ESRI Shapefile" )`
Since I'm new to programming I don't see a good way to do this. 
Could you help me out with this?

Comment: Are you trying to write each of the dataframes in the list `shapes` as its own shapefile? For this you'd want to make a vector of the names, e.g., `c("shape_1", "shape_2")` (or look at the `paste` function) and use a `for` loop or `mapply` to iterate over the elements of the list.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get it completly though. Could you make an example how to do it exaclty? And why use mapply insted of lapply?

Comment: And yes, I'm trying to write each of the dataframes of my list `shapes` as its own shapefile

Comment: e.g., `for (i in 1:length(shapes)) writeOGR(shapes[[i]], dsn= "", layer= shape_names[i], driver= "ESRI Shapefile" )` where `shape_names` is the vector of file names